# jQuery dark-mode toggle only half working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Creating a dark-mode toggle for an assignment, but it only works for 50%

Created 2 classes that should change the body's background + text color.

Toggling ON darkmode works fine, toggling it of to return to light-mode doesnt seem to work. Cannot seem to get the 'dark' class removed for some reason and changed to the  'light' class

```js
$('.switch').click(function() { 
        if ($('body').not('dark')) {
            $('body').addClass('dark');
        } 
        else if ($('body').hasClass('dark')) {
            $('body').removeClass('dark');
            $('body').addClass('light');
        }

});
```

```css
.dark {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: .5s all ease;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.light {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: .5s all ease;
    color: #000000;
}


/* ----------------------------- SLIDER -----------------------------*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
/*  float: right;*/
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #696969;
}

/*
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #696969;
}
*/

input:checked + .slider::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Switch theme </p> 

<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: `.not('dark')` will always be true, because the selector `'dark'` refers to a node type `<dark>`. You want a class selector: `.not('.dark')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always simplify your code and have the `light` styles be the default for `body` then simply toggle `dark` on `CHANGE` not `CLICK`.

When using `click` on the switch you are actually triggering your change function twice. However, the proper way to handle it is like a checkbox that it is and use `change`.

Also `not('dark')` won't work as `dark` isn't a selector so the `if` statement will never work.

```js
$(document).on("change",".switch",function() { 
   $("body").toggleClass("dark");
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: .5s all ease;
    color: #000000;
}

body.dark {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: .5s all ease;
    color: #ffffff;
}




/* ----------------------------- SLIDER -----------------------------*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
/*  float: right;*/
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #696969;
}

/*
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #696969;
}
*/

input:checked + .slider::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p> Switch theme </p> 

<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @vorkot1, I'm not 100% sure. I was testing your code and experienced that when I remembered when you are dealing with select, radio and checkboxes you should always use `change`.